# Use numpy to translate huge array of 2-byte strings to corresponding 1-byte strings according to a fixed mapping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, translation

I have a set of 12 distinct 2-byte strings which map to a set of 12 corresponding 1-byte strings according to the following translation dictionary:

```
translation_dict = {'AC': '2', 'AG': '3', 'AT': '4',
                    'CA': '5', 'CG': '6', 'CT': '7', 
                    'GA': '8', 'GC': '9', 'GT': 'a', 
                    'TA': 'b', 'TC': 'c', 'TG': 'd'}
```

I need some method for translating a huge `numpy.char.array` of the 2-byte strings to their corresponding 1-byte string mapping, as shown in the following example:

```
>>> input_array = numpy.char.array(['CA', 'CA', 'GC', 'TC', 'AT', 'GT', 'AG', 'CT'])
>>> output_array = some_method(input_arr)
>>> output_array
chararray(['5', '5', '9', 'c', '4', 'a', '3', '7'], dtype='S1')
```

I want to know if there is a fast numpy.char.array method for translating huge arrays of 2-byte strings; I am aware that I can use 'numpy.vectorize' with a function that explicitly looks up the 1-byte dictionary value for each 2-byte key, but this is relatively slow. I can't figure out to use `numpy.chararray.translate`, although it seems like that only works for 1-byte:1-byte mapping in any event.

Comment: Define "huge".  Millions?  Billions?  Trillions?

Comment: Why is the input in a `numpy.char.array`?  Is that something you can change?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser "huge" is on the order of billions in this case and the `numpy.char.array` is not necessary, I used it in the example since I was still holding out for discovering a clever use of `chararray.translate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such search operations, NumPy has [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), so allow me to suggest an approach with it -

```
def search_dic(dic, search_keys):
    # Extract out keys and values
    k = dic.keys()
    v = dic.values()

    # Use searchsorted to locate the indices
    sidx = np.argsort(k)
    idx = np.searchsorted(k,search_keys, sorter=sidx)

    # Finally index and extract out the corresponding values
    return np.take(v,sidx[idx])
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: translation_dict = {'AC': '2', 'AG': '3', 'AT': '4',
    ...:                     'CA': '5', 'CG': '6', 'CT': '7', 
    ...:                     'GA': '8', 'GC': '9', 'GT': 'a', 
    ...:                     'TA': 'b', 'TC': 'c', 'TG': 'd'}

In [47]: s = np.char.array(['CA', 'CA', 'GC', 'TC', 'AT', 'GT', 'AG', 'CT'])

In [48]: search_dic(translation_dict, s)
Out[48]: 
array(['5', '5', '9', 'c', '4', 'a', '3', '7'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: This works great -- thanks for showing me a new application for `numpy.searchsorted` :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about searching for the mininal elements and re-indexing:

```
uniq, inv_idx = np.unique(input_array, return_inverse=True)

np.array([translation_dict[u] for u in uniq])[inv_idx]

#array(['5', '5', '9', 'c', '4', 'a', '3', '7'],
#  dtype='<U1')
```

**Benchmark:**

```
import time

x = np.random.choice(list(translation_dict.keys()),1000000)

t = time.time()
uniq, inv_idx = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
res = np.array([translation_dict[u] for u in uniq])[inv_idx]
print("Colonel Beauvel timing is:" + (time.time()-t))

t = time.time()
res = search_dic(translation_dict, x)
print("Divakar timimng is:" + str(time.time()-t))

#Colonel Beauvel timing is:0.32760000228881836
#Divakar timing is:0.10920000076293945
```

Divakar wins hands down, three times better!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly hackish but fast approach using a cheap "hash":

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

translation_dict = {'AC': '2', 'AG': '3', 'AT': '4',
                    'CA': '5', 'CG': '6', 'CT': '7', 
                    'GA': '8', 'GC': '9', 'GT': 'a', 
                    'TA': 'b', 'TC': 'c', 'TG': 'd'}

keys, values = map(np.char.array, zip(*translation_dict.items()))

N = 1000000
mock_data = keys[np.random.randint(0,12,(N,))]

def lookup(hash_fun, td, data):
    keys, values = map(np.char.array, zip(*td.items()))
    keys_ = hash_fun(keys)
    assert len(set(keys_)) == len(keys)
    data = hash_fun(data)
    lookup = np.empty(max(keys_) + 1, values.dtype)
    lookup[keys_] = values
    return lookup[data].view(np.chararray)

def hash_12(table):
    unit = {8:np.uint32, 4:np.uint16, 2:np.uint8}[table.dtype.itemsize]
    lookup = table.view(np.ndarray).view(unit)
    return (lookup[1::2]<<1) + lookup[::2]

def search_dic(dic, search_keys):
    # Extract out keys and values
    k = dic.keys()
    v = dic.values()

    # Use searchsorted to locate the indices
    sidx = np.argsort(k)
    idx = np.searchsorted(k, search_keys.view(np.ndarray), sorter=sidx)

    # Finally index and extract out the corresponding values
    return np.take(v,sidx[idx])

def uniq(translation_dict, input_array):
    uniq, inv_idx = np.unique(input_array, return_inverse=True)
    return np.char.array([translation_dict[u] for u in uniq])[inv_idx]


# correctness
print(np.all(lookup(hash_12, translation_dict, mock_data)
             == search_dic(translation_dict, mock_data)))
print(np.all(lookup(hash_12, translation_dict, mock_data)
             == uniq(translation_dict, mock_data)))

# performance
print('C_Beauvel {:9.6f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: uniq(
    translation_dict, mock_data), number=10)/10))
print('Divakar   {:9.6f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: search_dic(
    translation_dict, mock_data), number=10)/10))
print('PP        {:9.6f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: lookup(
    hash_12, translation_dict, mock_data), number=10)/10))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
C_Beauvel  0.622123 secs
Divakar    0.050903 secs
PP         0.011464 secs
```